# SQLAlchemy filter_by several item from same column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm

There are 2 tables in DB with relationship between them by ext column in Player table.

Player id/names are 1000+ and ExtPlayer columns are several too.  It takes top 5 players for query its ExtPlayer data together in one or few queries  with `filter()` or `filter_by()` and avoid to load all ExtPlayer table.

List of `top = [x.id for x in player_top]`

I tried to query like these or some similar during my trying

`ext_data = ExtPlayer.query.filter_by(player_id=top).all()` or

```
db.session.query(ExtPlayer).filter(
    or_(ExtPlayer.player_id.like(top1),...,
        ExtPlayer.player_id.like(top5))
)
```

It below models/tables simplified

```
lass Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lastseen = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    ext = db.relationship('ExtPlayer', backref='extplayer', cascade="all, delete")


class ExtPlayer(db.Model):
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    trophies = db.Column(db.Integer)
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'))
```

thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for:

```
ext_data = db.session.query(ExtPlayer).filter(ExtPlayer.player_id.in_(top)).all()
```

Comment: top cannot insert directly because it is a list.  it is return a error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object ExtPlayer('4715', '3785', '912', '229', 'None', '1') is not legal as a SQL literal value`